# Recall/delete email from G Suite Business account

Tags: gmail, email, google-workspace-for-business

An email was sent with sensitive information to a group email address that includes all users in a company account. Is it possible to recall this email?

It was sent to an all@domain.tld, which is a group email. All company users are subscribed to that group. We use Gmail.

If it's not possible for the administrator to recall or delete the email, can the user who sent the email do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Security Investigation Tool](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7492003) to delete these messages from every user's inbox. If you do not have G Suite Enterprise you can leverage [GAMADV-XTD Users-Gmail-Messages-Threads](https://github.com/taers232c/GAMADV-XTD3/wiki/Users-Gmail-Messages-Threads#manage-messagesthreads) for this by issuing something like:

```
gam all users delete messages query rfc822msgid:random-message-id-here@mail.gmail.com doit
```

Comment: Just regarding the Tool, please note "Some features in the security investigation tool—for example, data related to Gmail and Drive—are not available with Cloud Identity Premium or Enterprise Standard editions".

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do it with a GUI if you have Google Workspaces Enterprise using the [Security Investigation Tool](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7581662?hl=en#zippy=%2Cget-started-with-your-investigation)

Much like "crossing the streams" in Ghostbusters you can also do it with a [documented](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/Command-Reference:-Email) series of commands GAM. Be very very careful with this as an improperly formatted command would likely result in all life as you know it stopping instantaneously and every molecule in your body exploding at the speed of light, or at the very least A LOT of deleted emails by mistake.

Syntax:

```
gam user <who> delete|trash|untrash messages|threads query <gmail search> [doit] [maxto<action> <number>]
```

Some Examples:

```
gam group facultystaff delete messages query "Subject: Fwd: bla bla bla" doit maxtomodify 5

gam user user@domain.org delete messages query "Subject: very secret documents" doit maxtomodify 5

gam all users delete messages query "rfc822msgid:CAD+g0fUfmNZZmYpcMDmECqZuok6KGkC_hP+qJA@mail.gmail.com>" doit
```

Comment: Just regarding the Tool, please note "Some features in the security investigation tool—for example, data related to Gmail and Drive—are not available with Cloud Identity Premium or Enterprise Standard editions".